# Remove the amidst value of a name into other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been working on splitting out some names into several columns in MS SQL server, and what i've got left is a last name and an amidst value (John OF THE Smithsons)

So heres what I want to do, I've got several examples:

```
of Holland
Of the Clothson, 
England, from
```

So I've got 3 variations of this, (of, of the, from) which can be in random places in the string. What I want to do is remove these values from the LastName column and move them to the Amidst column so I'm left with,

```
LastName|Amidst
--------------
Holland |of
clothson|of the
England |from
```

what would be the best way to do this? Is it possible to move the values I want to select into a table and reference from there? I'm not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, giant `case` expressions might be the best way:

```
select (case when col like '% of the%'
             then ltrim(rtrim(replace(col, ' of the', '')))
             when col like '% of%'
             then ltrim(rtrim(replace(col, ' of', '')))
             when col like '% from%'
             then ltrim(rtrim(replace(col, ' from', '')))
             else col
        end) as new_col,
       (case when col like '% of the%'
             then 'of the'
             when col like '% of%'
             then 'of'
             when col like '% from%'
             then 'from'
        end) as new_midst
```

Comment: I expect it won't be limited to these three, could be better to have a helper table and work from that instead?